# Class method called by only presenting object name

Tags: java, object, methods

I have the following piece of code

```
public class DriverTester {
  public static void main(...){
    // test empty constructor
    Person p1 = new Person();
    System.out.println("p1: " + p1); 
  }
}

public class Person {
   private String name;
   // Empty constructor 
   public Person () {
   }
   // getter avoided for simplicity
   public String toString() {
     return "Mr.or Ms. "+this.name;
   }
}
```

It compiles, runs succesfully and shows "Mr or Mrs null". So, that would b e the result of calling the `toString` method.

I don't understand the syntax in of the print line method. How is it that simply the name of the object `p1` runs a given method. How does it know which method to run? Shouldn't the syntax be

```
System.out.println("p1: " + p1.getName());
```

or

```
System.out.println("p1: " + p1.toString());
```

Thanks for any clarification

Comment: All objects are children of the `Object` class which has a `toString()` method. The `println()` method accepts an `Object`. So it knows it can call toString() on the argument. Same goes for string concatenation.

Comment: Whenever an object is used in a `String` context, as it is in the `println`, it's `toString()` method is called.  You are right in that `System.out.println("p1: " + p1.toString())` would be more verbose and correct.

Answer (score 4):

When concatenating strings, such as in this line:

```
System.out.println("p1: " + p1);
```

Java will call the `toString()` method to convert any object to a `String` for concatenation.  Java ensures that this method exists on all objects, because it's defined on the [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) class, which every class implicitly inherits from.

Additionally, if a `null` is concatenated, then Java will convert that into the *String* `"null"`.

The [Java Language Specification, section 5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11), covers "String Conversion":

> - If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four    ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the    toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but
>     if    the result of invoking the toString method is null, then the
>     string    "null" is used instead.

Comment: Good answer, but you might want to add `toString()` is defined in `java.lang.Object`, ensuring every single class in Java's type system (AFAIK) has at least a basic implementation.

Comment: Now completely makes sense - if a string is needed in context of user and no specific method called then toString is run

Answer (score 2):

`PrintStream` used by `System.out.println` [uses `String.valueOf`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
649     public void print(Object obj) {
650         write(String.valueOf(obj));
651     }
```

which in turn uses the Object's [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method provided the `Object` itself is not `null`, otherwise the literal `"null"` is returned.

```
2837    public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
2838        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
2839    }
```

Comment: Much thanks, makes complete sense. Thansk for sharing you knowledge.